# Does Windows 7 make it any easier to upgrade downloaded applications on restricted users' desktops?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, desktop-management

I'm regularly asked to login to a user's machine and upgrade their desktop's version of TweetDeck, or Flash, or Firefox, etc.  I would love to let the end user just upgrade it themselves, especially for some of the apps that have an extremely simple upgrade process like TweetDeck.  However, they are restricted users (for good reason) and we're not going to elevate their rights.

Does Windows 7 offer any assistance here?

Comment: Yep, you tell the end user to reformat their computer to a fresh install and give themselves an admin account

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

The user will be promted to enter a password for an account that has the correct access level to install the software.

If you give the restricted user the password they are no longer restrcited as they can choose to remember it. You are then forced to alter the administrator password, which will only work easily if you're controlling these accounts seperately on a domain controller (or similar).